Bun stdin one line only
I am implementing a cli tool using bun. I have to collect inputs from user during runtime and I specifically need only one line from stdin. This is what I have implemented so far by referring the docs:
async function getInput() {
  for await (const input of console) {
    return input;
  }
}

async function liveTest() {
  /* some code here */
  console.log("input1:");
  await getInput();
  /* some code here */
  console.log("input2:");
  await getInput();
  /* some code here */
}

liveTest();

I am running it using bun file.ts command. I am observing a problem where the input2 is not actually being collected. It just directly moves to the remaining code.
Can someone explain why and provide a fix/workaround?

This worked for me:
async function input(label: string) {
    process.stdout.write(label);
    for await (const input of console) {
        return input;
    }
}

console.log(await input("First line: "));
console.log(await input("Second line: "));


you can use then()


async function getInput() {
  for await (const input of console) {
    return console;
  }
}

async function liveTest() {
  /* some code here */
  console.log("input1:");
  getInput().then();
  /* some code here */
  console.log("input2:");
  getInput().then();
  /* some code here */
}

liveTest();



